# How to add custom field on the detail section of custom lightning page?

Tags: lightning, custom-field, lightning-record-page

I have a custom lightning record page created for a custom object. The detail section has some set of fields. Now I want to add one more custom field to the detail section of the custom lightning record page. I have added the custom field to the page layout and set appropriate FLS. But still the field is not showing in the lightning record page. Is there anything I have to do here?

Answer (score 2):

There is a separate Tab named as Fields which has the standard and custom fields of the corresponding object chosen, from where we can drag the required field  and paste it in the appropriate place of Details section.
[image]